# Android Project on GITHUB

Tags: android, github, version-control, git-bash

I am trying to push my android project from android studio to github using version control.It will create the repository on github but failed to push giving error

Cannot spawn C:\Users\Lenovo.AndroidStudio3.5\system\tmp\intellij-git-askpass.bat: No such file or directory bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1) could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory

I have tried reinstalling the gitbash with the latest update but giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your remote like this:

`git remote set-url <your-remote-name> https://<your-username>:<your-password>@github.com/<your-username>/<your-repository-name>.git`

with your info